# Type for storing `DiffTime` in database

Tags: database, postgresql, haskell, numbers

I need to store a `DiffTime` from the `time` library in a database (PostgreSQL) and have three options for converting to a database type:

1. Integer using `fromIntegral . fromEnum`
2. Numeric via Rational `toRational`
3. Real using `realToFrac`

The integer is exact, but rather large, since stored in pico seconds (10^12). Numeric is also exact, but it is potentially very expensive to calculate a `Rational`, since it has to calculate `gcd` for numerator and denominator. The real is inexact, but maybe that doesn't matter.

My time granularity would never be below minutes or larger than a couple of days. I need to make exact calculations. Speed is probably not an issue.

Which option should I choose and what are the implications? Should Rational generally be avoided when handling user submitted numbers like explained in [`scientific`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/scientific-0.3.4.10/docs/Data-Scientific.html) library?

Comment: Note that `fromEnum` truncates to 0 for values that don't fit into an `Int`. If that range is large enough for you, you may as well just use a Postgres `bigint`. To convert a `DiffTime` into an `Integer` you should use [`diffTimeToPicoseconds`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.7.0.1/docs/Data-Time-Clock.html#v:diffTimeToPicoseconds).

Comment: Thanks for the warning. I did see that function, but also need to do a conversion for `NominalDiffTime`, which doesn't have a function like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you might be looking for [interval](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-datetime.html). The hasql library has an encoder and a decoder for DiffTime with the name [interval](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hasql-0.19.15.2/docs/Hasql-Encoders.html#v:interval) as well.

Comment: Thanks I'll look at that. Have started to use `hasql`. Any recommendations for selecting int, rational or float and rational vs. scientific?

Comment: I think int and float are not precise enough so probably go with scientific, which is supposed to be faster and safer than rational afaik, if you can't just use interval.